# Using meta tags with a customized facebook share button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

I am using a facebook share button customized by my own design.

First : I have an a-tag as follow :

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={$mainsite|escape:'url'}{$OBJECT->getURL()|urlencode}&amp;t={$OBJECT->getShareMessage()|escape}" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;" class="btn-facebook"></a>
```

And the class 'btn-facebook' calls the background image of my customized design.

Second, the page has meta tags that gathers some open graph properties as title, image of the page,...

My problem is that when I click on this a-tag, I have indeed a message on my facebook wall, but I don't have any title or image displayed in this message. Is there a way to do that ?

By the way, I know I can use the feed dialog, but is it possible to couple this latter to opne graph meta tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I managed to debug by using the feed dialog box. This is the way to use it :

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=$app_id;link=$link
picture=$picture&name=$name&caption=$caption&description=$description
```

Refer to the doc [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)